# Random system halt (no BSOD) due to watchdog

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, shutdown, kernel

I have a Sony SVE15118FG laptop running windows 8.1 that has been doing me well however recently it has started while gaming randomly shutting off. I'm referring to an immediate power off followed by ~15 seconds before I can press the power button again to turn it on.

This only happens when I am gaming (usually league of legends, sometimes other games) - but it's not related to what's happening in the game - Sometimes I can play for 2 - 3 days without turning off and playing for ~8 hours per day. Other times I will play for 4 hours and have had 5-6 crashes.

It's not malware related - I've done two clean installs and the issue still persists.
It doesn't seem to be update related - I've had crashes both on a fully updated system and a clean 8.1 iso installed system.

The logs always contain

> "The system watchdog timer was triggered." just after a crash.

Followed by

> "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."

and finally

> "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error is caused because the system stopped responding and the hardware watchdog triggered a system reset."

Possibly related:
There are several warnings in the log from "BTHUSB"

> "A command sent to the adapter has timed out. The adapter did not respond."

The system is no overclocked.

The only recent change is that I have a few new logitech devices
G700 Mouse,
G710+ Keyboard,
G430 Headset

I don't believe it is heat related, it can happen 20 minutes after the laptop has been on, or sometimes hours or days - I've checked the vents, and it's always running on a cooling pad, I've also tried having a fan running over it.

There is no BSOD or dumps anywhere that I can find.

I'm at my wits end trying to debug this, can anyone help me try to track down the source?

DXdiag: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb087d17934d92390d67

Comment: If this problem still exists after reinstalling Windows then you have a hardware problem.  Your hardware is either overheating or its about to fail.  You have to determine if the hardware is overheating or the operating system is crashing.  Only you can determine this.  I would just start the warranty process on the device to be honest.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504